# VBA calling same function gives 2 different answers

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function that gives me the last open row, that I call form 2 worksheets. When I call the function I get a different answers from each sheet. The one gives me the correct value, and the other worksheet gives me a value that is one less. I have tried breaking the function down, but in the end the difference comes in at the second half of the main row (the long row), where I use `Abs`.

I probably did not explain it very well, but the code runs with a button from two different sheets, and looks at the same data on one of the two sheets. Meaning, the code runs on the **exact same data** with different results, depending on the button I press. (Both buttons call the exact same macro to run the code)

I got the code from a website that showed all the ways that a person can get the last open row from a worksheet.

My code:

```
Public Function lastOpenRow(sheetName) As Long
    lastOpenRow = 1
    With sheetName
        For a = 1 To 50
            Count = Worksheets(sheetName).Cells(Rows.Count, a).End(xlUp).Offset(Abs(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).value <> ""), 0).Row
            If lastOpenRow < Count Then
                lastOpenRow = Count
            End If
        Next a
        MsgBox "The lastOpenRow and Count = " & lastOpenRow & " " & Count

    End With
End Function
```

Any idea why I get two different answers?

Comment: IIRC .End(xlUp) will stop at the first blank row it finds, does one of your sheets have a bank row in the data?

Overall this code is pretty inefficient. Hopefully your data has at least one column that's *guaranteed* to have data in every cell. Consider using just that column to determine your last row instead of looping through the first 50 columns.

Comment: `Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).value` is referring to whatever is the currently active sheet.  Are you sure you didn't want to refer to the specific sheet `Worksheets(sheetName)`, i.e. `Worksheets(sheetName).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).value`?

Comment: Geez @YowE3K, can you take a break please? :D

Comment: Hi, I probably did not explain it very well, but the code runs with a button from two different sheets, and looks at the same data on one of the two sheets. Meaning, the code runs on the exact same data with different results, depending on the button I press. (Both buttons call the exact same macro to run the code)

Comment: @Excelosaurus What?  Take a break and do **real** work?  How boring that would be!!

Comment: @AlfaBravo - If you have a button on two different sheets, and both buttons are passing the same value to the parameter `sheetName`, then it is **definitely** the unqualified `Cells` reference causing the issue because the active sheet will be different in the two cases.  (BTW Your `With sheetname` statement, and the corresponding `End With` can be removed from your code - you aren't making use of them anywhere.)

Comment: Mmm, the way you explain it is indeed what happens, so you understand my problem then. "Unqualified Cells"? Can you give me an example of what a qualified cell in this case would have looked like and then I can take it from there...

Comment: `Worksheets(sheetName).Cells(...` is qualified to specify what worksheet `Cells` is a property of.  `Cells(...` (without anything in front of it) does not qualify it by stating which worksheet it is a property of and therefore defaults to `ActiveSheet.Cells(...` (which in your case is whichever sheet you press the button on).

Comment: That was it, if I had met you sooner I could have been finished with lunch by now.  :)  If you put it in an answer then I will mark it correct, otherwise thanks a million!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Always** qualify references to `Cells`, `Rows`, `Columns`, `Range`, etc unless you are absolutely certain that you want to refer to whichever sheet is currently active:

```
Public Function lastOpenRow(sheetName) As Long
    lastOpenRow = 1
    With Worksheets(sheetName) 'I'll make use of this by just typing ".something"
                               ' rather than saying "Worksheets(sheetName).something"
        For a = 1 To 50
            Count = .Cells(.Rows.Count, a).End(xlUp).Offset(Abs(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).value <> ""), 0).Row
            If lastOpenRow < Count Then
                lastOpenRow = Count
            End If
        Next a
        MsgBox "The lastOpenRow and Count = " & lastOpenRow & " " & Count

    End With
End Function
```

Comment: I'd even add that when you want to refer to whatever is active, do use `ActiveXYZ.Method` to clearly state your intent, such as `ActiveSheet.Range()`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Oh well, might as well post anyways. At least I've declared all variables ;-)

```
Public Function LastOpenRow(ByVal psSheetName As String) As Long
    Dim result As Long
    Dim colIndex As Long
    Dim colLastRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(psSheetName)
        For colIndex = 1 To 50
            colLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, colIndex).End(xlUp).Offset(Abs(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Value <> ""), 0).Row
            If result < colLastRow Then
                result = colLastRow
            End If
        Next
    End With

    LastOpenRow = result
End Function
```

Not sure about the offset part, though.

Comment: I must admit, that `Offset` part has me stumped too.  It seems to be increasing the count of rows in the column being looked at by 1, unless the last used cell in column A is blank (i.e. a calculated blank, not an empty cell).